# How to instantiate an ArrayList<String[]> already containing multitudinous String[1]?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, instantiation, objectinstantiation

```
private ArrayList<String[]> action = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Suppose my goal with the above is to fill `action` with twenty empty `String[3]`. The quickest way I know of is:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; ++i) {
    action.add(new String[3]);
}
```

Is there a more space efficient way to instantiate this object?

Comment: new String[1] ? you should add String.

Comment: Not sure what this means

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Why ? This is an `ArrayList` of `String[]`

Comment: why would you want String array of 1 element. User String variable instead.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi That's an example, he also coud add an array of 2 elements. But I get your point =).

Comment: That's the way I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
 String[][] s = new String[20][3];
 List<String[]> action  = new ArrayList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

or

```
 String[][] s = new String[20][3];
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    action.add(s[i]);           
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying `new String[1]` to your data requires a closure statement which is not concise at all in Java 7. In Java 8 your code is like:

```
List<String[]> collect = IntStream.range(0, 20)
    .mapToObj(x -> new String[3])
    .collect(Collectors.<String[]>toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

`String[][] action = new String[20][3]`